# Append an object in an array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I want to append an object in an array.

For example,

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        [array addObject:@[@"Any"]];
    }
```

It gives an output like this:

```
array: (
        (
        Any
    ),
        (
        Any
    ),
        (
        Any
    ),
        (
        Any
    ),
        (
        Any
    )
)
```

Now I want to append object at index 3 of an array so that it could appear like below:

```
array: (
            (
            Any
        ),
            (
            Any
        ),
            (
            Any
        ),
            (
            Any, Where, How, When
        ),
            (
            Any
        )
    )
```

Comment: It is index 2, not index 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use function insertObjectAtIndex to achieve it.

[array insertObject:anObject atIndex:2];

Comment: This gives an output like this: `array: ((Any),(Any),(Any),(Any),Where, How, When,(Any))`. However, I want `Where, How, When,` inside the braces with `Any` like: `(Any, Where, How, When )`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you...

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:@[[[array objectAtIndex:2] firstObject],@"Where",@"How",@"When"]];
```

Comment: Are you sure that you typed correctly? This does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @Desdenova Not exactly, to be honest ))) but I edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    [array addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"Any"]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", array);

NSMutableArray *subArray = [array objectAtIndex:3];
[subArray addObjectsFromArray:@[@"Where", @"How", @"When"]];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Note, `@[]` creates an instance of `NSArray` class which cannot be modified later. You can modify only instances of `NSMutableArray` class.